Managing multiple Looker Studios reports from one Template
I manage multiple websites for clients.  They all get monthly reports with web analytics (Google Analytics 4 data source) delivered to them.
My problem is when I add a new metric to a report, or add something different to one report (for example a button that links to the first page of the report), then I have to edit each report separately.
Is there a way to manage multiple reports from one template?  ie - I make a change in the template and it pushes that change to multiple reports?
I've tried build one Looker Studio report with a Data Source control filter, but then each client would be able to view other clients' data.
Also, I'm not sure there's a way to ensure that when you share the report with each separate client, the link is set up so that their data source is selected when they pull up the report.
Essentially, I have 10+ clients looking at the exact same data each month, and when they look at the report I want them to only see their data, while not having to have 10 separate reports to manage every time I make an addition or change.
Is this possible?
